# Javascript - Anyway setting a default value for a property that has YET been created?

Tags: javascript

Supposedly I have an object called `cache`, and I'd like to have `cache.a`, `cache.b`, `cache.c`, ..., literally every `cache.whatever` to use a predefined value `VALUE` as default, before I explicitly set them to something like `cache.a = 'FOOBAR'`. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this like

```
function Cache(){
    this.GetValue = function(propertyName){
        if(!this[propertyName]){
            this[propertyName] = "Value";
        }
        return this[propertyName];
    }

    this.SetValue = function(propertyName, Value){
        this[propertyName] = Value;
    }
    return this;
}
```

**Edited**:

You can use it like...

```
var cache = new Cache();
alert(cache.GetValue("a")); // It will alert "Value"

var newValueOfA = "New Value";
cache.SetValue("a", newValueOfA);

alert(cache.GetValue("a")); // It will alert "New Value"
```

Comment: @Kay, Check the Edited part of answer.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Your best bet is to introduce an extra layer of indirection:

```
var Cache = function(){
  this.values = {};
};

Cache.prototype.set = function(key, value) {
  this.values[key] = value;
};

Cache.prototype.get = function(key) {
  var result = this.values[key];
  if (typeof result === 'undefined') {
     return 'default';
  }
  return result;
};
```